# How can I use setTimeout to return a JSX element inside an if condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement a search feature, using custom hooks, and retrieving data from an external API. The problem is that when the user enters an invalid search term, it immediately returns the JSX element inside the if condition. How can I delay showing the JSX element using setTimeout, so first show the user a spinner or something, then redirect them to the previous page. This is what I have:

```
if (!movies[0])
    return (
        <>
            <Spinner />
            <h1>NO RESULTS FOUND</h1>
        </>
    );
```

This is what i'd like to do theoretically:

```
if (!movies[0]) => show Spinner (for 200ms) => setTimeout(show error and redirect after 200ms, 200)
```

how could I implement this in react?

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe try something like this :

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
  let timer = setTimeout(() => {
    setLoading(false);
  }, 2000);

  return () => { clearTimeout(timer) };
}, [];

return (
  <>
    {loading ? <div>Loading</div> : <div>...<div>}
  </>
);
```

Comment: Actually, my loader is working and implemented in my custom hook where i'm also getting the "movie" info. So I do get a spinner when it's loading, what I need is when the results from the movie array returns empty, I need to show a spinner before informing the user that results weren't found, and then possibly redirect them back to the home page!